# Error: (dberror) 268 - column ambiguously defined: ROLLNO: line 1 col 7 (at pos 7)

Tags: java, sql, hana

I'm trying to create a view in SAP HANA using multiple tables (basically 2 tables) where `rollNo` is the primary key column in both the tables but I'm getting the following error:

> Error: (dberror) 268 - column ambiguously defined: ROLLNO: line 1 col 7 (at pos 7)

I've tried creating this view by using the concept of JOINS in SQL.
The following is the method in the DAO class:

```
public Response CreatingMultiTableViews()
{
    try
    {
        session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx=session.beginTransaction();
        SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery(" create VIEW ABCD As Select rollNo,name,english From ClassOne  JOIN ClassTwo ON ClassOne.rollNo= ClassTwo.rollNo");
        query.executeUpdate();
        response.setStatus("200");
        response.setMessage("successfull");
        tx.commit();
        return response;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        response.setStatus("500");
        response.setMessage("unsuccessfull");
        tx.rollback();
        return response;
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

This is the method invocation in controller class.
It will call the method that is responsible for performing the join and creating the respective view.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/multiView",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json",consumes="application/json")
public Response CreatingMultiTableViews()
{
    return service.CreatingMultiTableViews();
}
```

The method is expected to join both the tables on `rollNo` column but it shows the above stated error the column `rollNo` is a primary key for both the tables that I'm applying the join operation on.

Answer (score 0):

Use table alias in your sql and use them to say which column `rollNo` you want in your SELECT

```
create VIEW ABCD As 
Select c1.rollNo, name, english 
From ClassOne c1  
JOIN ClassTwo c2 ON c1.rollNo = c2.rollNo
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer i have used the alias on other columns aswell doing so has given me the solution for my query.

Comment: create VIEW ABCD As Select c1.rollNo, c1.name, c1.english From ClassOne c1  JOIN ClassTwo c2 ON c1.rollNo = c2.rollNo